# How does Exit Function return to parent function? In my case it exits both the functions

Tags: windows, function, vbscript

```
Function A1()
  A1 = 0
  retunrvalue = A2()
  WScript.Echo "retunrvalue of A2 is:" & retunrvalue 
End Function

Function A2()
  A2 = 1
  Exit Function
End Function

A1()
'Exit function in A2 returns directly here rather returning to A1
```

When I called A2 from A1, I'm expecting A2 exit should return back to A1. But it doesn't return back to A1. How can we achieve it?

Comment: Remove `Exit Function` you don't need it.

Comment: Can't reproduce. The code does exactly what you expect when I tested it on a Server 2012 R2 test box.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers it works, but its pointless.

Comment: I don't disagree with that.

Comment: it was due to typo.. i corrected it.. thanks

Comment: @NaviKeshDoddi let me guess `retunrvalue` versus `returnvalue`?

Comment: no.. typo in wscript. but it did not throwed error.

Answer (score 1):

A2 neither **retuns** nor **retutns** to A1; but this

```
type 43462226.vbs
Function A1()
 A1 = 0
 retunrvalue = A2()
 wscript.echo "retunrvalue of A2 is:" &retunrvalue
End Function
Function A2()
 A2 = 1
 Exit Function
End Function

A1()

cscript 43462226.vbs
retunrvalue of A2 is:1
```

proves via the output that A2 really **returns** to A1. The `Exit Function` does **not** exit A1.